# Создать Счет, связать с Заказом покупателя, перенести в Счет товары из связанного Заказа

Tags: moysklad-json-api, мойсклад

Создаём Счёт, связанный с Заказом покупателя через POST-запрос, тело которого содержит:

```
"customerOrder": {
   "meta": {
       "href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/customerorder/ORD_ID",
       "type": "customerorder"
   }
},
```

В результате получаем новый Счёт привязанный к Заказу, с нужным номером, тем же контрагентом, но без позиций.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать перенос списка товаров из связанного Заказа?

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю так:

1. [выгружаю позиции заказа](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F) циклом, тк их может быть больше 100
2. [добавляю эти позиции в счет](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E), тоже циклом

циклы нужны тк получать и привязывать можно не более 100 позиций за один запрос к апи